# Curve (spline, bezier path, etc) described by a set of base points

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

As an input I have set of 'base' points (e.g. 9 points), and as an output I must return another set of points, which describe a curve.

A1-A9 is an input; these are the 'base' points. My task is to return a set of points, from which the user can build the depicted curve, the black line from A1-A9

[image: Puzzle piece]

My mathematical skills are low, and Googling is not very helpful. As I understand, this can be a cubic spline. I have found some C-based source code, but this code loops endlessly when I try to build spline parts, where `nextPoint.x < currentPoint.x`.

Please, explain me, what kind of splines, bezier paths, or other constructs I should use for my task. It will be very good if you point me to code, an algorithm, or a good manual for dummies.

Comment: The output points are the actual pixels of the resulting curve?

Comment: given just the 9 blue points there are lots of different curves one could draw through them. You need to clarify exacty what is input and desired output.

Comment: @george No, this question is fully specified.  Given any set of N points there are always infinitely many smooth curves that could be drawn through all of them.  Spline methods find the one which is optimal as measured by some quantity like magnitude of the second derivative or something like that.

Comment: @Josh, no, it's a mathematical abstraction, just coordinates.
Ggeorge, I has update picture. I hope, it's clarify.

Comment: The points you have are already coordinates along the curve, and -- given a couple more pieces of information -- can describe that curve, so to say that the output should be more coordinates doesn't really make anything clear; there are, as has been said, infinitely many curves. To figure out _which_ curve, you need those other pieces of information.

Comment: If I understand question - there are many smooth curves types, that could be drawn through base points. Unfortunately, I can't give more information to clarify situation. let's say, that as an input I have a set of points and step. As an output - other set of points which describe curve. This curve must be smooth enough. All other on my choice. Inclined to believe, I can use B-Spline, but I not sure. Maybe there are more easy and appropriate way.

Comment: I believe what you are after is a cubic b-spline (note in your points are not ordered monotonically in x which may cause problems with some simpler approaches) Here is a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)  Look at the pdf from Dr House referenced on the wiki page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I found the solution. For build 2D curve by basic points I do follow:
I found [this](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD) article about a cubic spline with C++ and C# examples. This example allows to find interpolation values of 'one dimension' cubic spline by base points. Because I need a two dimension cubic spline - I create two one dimension splines - for 'x' and 'y' axes. Next, Next, I was run a cycle from first point to end point with some step and in each iteration of cycle I found interpolation value. From interpolation value I was make a point. So, when cycle has be ended I get a curve.

pseudo code (using spline class from article pointed above):

```
- (array*)splineByBasePoints:(array*)basePoints
{
    int n = basePoints.count;
    cubic_spline xSpline, ySpline;
    xSpline.build_spline(basePoints.pointNumbers, basePoints.XValuesOfPoints, n);
    ySpline.build_spline(basePoints.pointNumbers, basePoints.YValuesOfPoints, n);
    array curve;
    int t = 1; //t - intermediate point. '1' because number of point, not index

    for (; t <= n; t += step)
    {
        [curve addToArray:PontWithXY([xSpline f:t], [ySpline f:t])];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Interpolation methods](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) to generate the intermediate points on your curve.

For example, given the CubicInterpolate function:

```
double CubicInterpolate(
   double y0,double y1,
   double y2,double y3,
   double mu)
{
   double a0,a1,a2,a3,mu2;

   mu2 = mu*mu;
   a0 = y3 - y2 - y0 + y1;
   a1 = y0 - y1 - a0;
   a2 = y2 - y0;
   a3 = y1;

   return(a0*mu*mu2+a1*mu2+a2*mu+a3);
}
```

to find the point halfway between `point[1]` and `point[2]` on a cubic spline, you would use:

```
newPoint.X = CubicInterpolate(point[0].X, point[1].X, point[2].X, point[3].X, 0.5);
newPoint.Y = CubicInterpolate(point[0].Y, point[1].Y, point[2].Y, point[3].Y, 0.5);
```

`point[0]` and `point[3]` do affect the section of the curve between `point[1]` and `point[2]`. At either end of the curve, simply use the end point again.

To ensure a roughly equal distance between points, you can calculate the distance between input points to determine how many intermediate points (and `mu` values) to generate. So, for points that are further apart, you would use many more `mu` values between `0` and `1`. Conversely, for points that are very close together, you may not need to add intermediate points at all.

Comment: Thanks, it's will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MATLAB license,

```
x = -4:4;
y = [0 .15 1.12 2.36 2.36 1.46 .49 .06 0];
cs = spline(x,[0 y 0]);
xx = linspace(-4,4,101);
y=ppval(cs,xx);
```